# API Gateway Invoke Endpoint works fine; Cloudfront returns 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've set up an AWS API Gateway proxy endpoint to a lambda function and deployed it to a stage called `auth`. The Invoke URL found on the API Gateway dashboard works just fine and executes my lambda.

However, I've created a Cloudfront distribution that I want to map to API Gateway. I set the Origin to the API Gateway URL and configured a behavior to forward `/auth/*` to the API Gateway origin:

[image]

### Origin Settings:

[image]

### Behavior Settings:

[image]

However, this doesn't work. I get a 403 Forbidden message from Cloudfront:

[image]

This is extremely confusing for me because I have an almost identical set up on another AWS account that works just fine. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Use curl/wget to test your API endpoint to see if it works. Check the logs of API gateway invocation.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried curl/postman/browser and I haven't made much headway, it's always the same 403.

Comment: That narrows down the problem in API gateway.

Comment: Yeah, cloudfront is definitely getting me to api gateway, because that 403 message is the same one you would get from an invalid api gateway route. Not sure where to go from there though. Like I said I've done very similar setups before and everything worked fine so I'm not too sure what's going on.

Comment: Did you use cloudformation like tool to create aws resources? Manual configuration always is error-prone.